# Getting lists where an element passes through every index in python?

Tags: python, list, permutation

Kind of a strange request.

Let's say I have the following list:

```
[1,2,3]
```

And I want something, say, the number 9, to pass through every index, to get the following list of lists:

```
[[9,1,2,3],
 [1,9,2,3],
 [1,2,9,3],
 [1,2,3,9]]
```

Any idea how to do this easily? Also, is there a name for this sort of thing?

Edit: I realize I can do something like the following:

```
lists=[]
for i in range(4):
  new_list = [1,2,3]
  new_list.insert(i,9)
  lists+=[new_list]
```

but I consider this inelegant. Thoughts?

Comment: The `for` loop is the best choice.  It's readable and easily understood.  Wrap it in a function and you're good to go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do something like

```
l = [1,2,3]
new_l = [l[:i] + [9] + l[i:] for i in range(len(l) + 1)]
```

Comment: Nice — I had just posted the same answer!

Comment: I was going to post the exact same thing.

Answer (score 3):

How about a for loop:

```
l = [1,2,3]
res = []
for i in xrange(len(l)+1):
    l2 = l[:]
    l2.insert(i,9)
    res.append(l2)
```

Here is another thing I thought of:

```
l = [1,2,3]
q = [l[:] for _ in range(len(l)+1)]
map(lambda(x):x.insert(q.index(x),9), q)
```

Then `q` will contain your list:

```
print q
[9, 1, 2, 3], [1, 9, 2, 3], [1, 2, 9, 3], [1, 2, 3, 9]]
```

Comment: Whoops, I edited my post around the same time that you posted this. I already had this solution; I'm looking for something "cuter" I guess. (Not that there's anything really wrong with this approach.)

Answer (score 0):

[enumerate](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/functions.html#enumerate) and [repeat](http://docs.python.org/2.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) are your friends.

```
from itertools import repeat

some_list = [1, 2, 3]
new_lists = []
new_elt = 9
for i, lst in enumerate(L[:] for L in repeat(some_list, len(some_list)+1))
    lst.insert(i, new_elt)
    new_lists.append(lst)

print new_lists
```

Comment: That list could be written as `[[1,2,3]] * 4` and then `4` replaced to allow variable length. And the call to enumerate is missing.

Comment: @Brian No, it cannot. That syntax creates 4 shallow copies of the list [1, 2, 3], meaning that instead of getting the 'moving nine' effect, all the resulting lists look like [9, 9, 9, 9, 1, 2, 3]. Try it in a REPL.